# Forge Integration request URL from request body

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to dynamically forge the integration request URL (http integration point) based on a value inside the body (json) of the request.

For the sake of simplicity, imagine the following request payload:

```
{ "country": "FR", ... }
```

And then based on the value of `"country"`, I'd like to create dynamic Endpoint URLs:

- Endpoint URL: `https://myserver/my-app/FR/` when `"country"` has `"FR"` as value
- Endpoint URL: `https://myserver/my-app/EN/` when `"country"` has `"EN"` as value

I have tried several things unsuccessfully (and I don't even know if it's possible atm, e.g. the docs mention path parameters, header parameters, query parameters, but not payload, except for mapping payloads).

Failed attempts:

```
https://my-server/my-app/${method.request.body.country}/

https://my-server/my-app/${method.request.body.path('$').country}/

https://my-server/my-app/${$util.parseJson($method.request.body).country}/
```

- Is what I'm trying to achieve possible?
- If so, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the endpoint URL can be mapped only from request parameters. It cannot be mapped from the elements of request body.